# How do I use localstorage with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage

I am trying to build a Trello clone using ReactJS with basic functionalities. I am using Redux for my state management. The problem is I cannot wrap my head around on how do I use localstorage to store the card component text.

What I am building?

- A basic Trello clone with 4 columns called TODO, DOING, DONE, REJECTED.
- I can add cards to any of the 4 columns.
- The cards can be moved from anywhere to any columns and also be rearranged(using react-beautiful-dnd)

What my problem?
Since I am using redux I am not able to save data into my localstorage. How do I approach to this problem?

My listReducer.js file

```
import { CONSTANTS } from "../actions";

let listID = 2;
let cardID = 10;

const initialState = [
  {
    title: "TODO",
    id: `list-${0}`,
    cards: [
      {
        id: `card-${0}`,
        text: "this is a card"
      },
      {
        id: `card-${1}`,
        text: "this is the second card"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "DOING",
    id: `list-${1}`,
    cards: [
      {
        id: `card-${2}`,
        text: "doing card 1"
      },
      {
        id: `card-${3}`,
        text: "doing card 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "DONE",
    id: `list-${2}`,
    cards: [
      {
        id: `card-${4}`,
        text: "done this is a card"
      },
      {
        id: `card-${5}`,
        text: "done this is the second card"
      },
      {
        id: `card-${6}`,
        text: "done this is the second card"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "REJECTED",
    id: `list-${3}`,
    cards: [
      {
        id: `card-${7}`,
        text: "rejected done this is a card"
      },
      {
        id: `card-${8}`,
        text: "rejected done this is the second card"
      },
      {
        id: `card-${9}`,
        text: "rejected done this is the second card"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const listReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CONSTANTS.ADD_LIST:
      const newList = {
        title: action.payload.text, ///here
        cards: [],
        id: `list-${listID}`
      };
      listID += 1;
      return [...state, newList];

    case CONSTANTS.ADD_CARD: {
      const newCard = {
        text: action.payload.text, ///here
        id: `card-${cardID}`
      };
      cardID += 1;

      const newState = state.map(list => {
        if (list.id === action.payload.listID) {
          ////here
          return {
            ...list,
            cards: [...list.cards, newCard]
          };
        } else {
          return list;
        }
      });

      return newState;
    }
    case CONSTANTS.DRAG_HAPPENED:
      const {
        droppableIdStart,
        droppableIdEnd,
        droppableIndexStart,
        droppableIndexEnd,
        draggableId
      } = action.payload;
      const newState = [...state];
      // in the same list
      if (droppableIdStart === droppableIdEnd) {
        const list = state.find(list => droppableIdStart === list.id);
        const card = list.cards.splice(droppableIndexStart, 1);
        list.cards.splice(droppableIndexEnd, 0, ...card);
      }

      // not in the same list
      if (droppableIdStart !== droppableIdEnd) {
        // list where drag happened
        const listStart = state.find(list => droppableIdStart === list.id);
        //pulling out the card from the list
        const card = listStart.cards.splice(droppableIndexStart, 1);
        //finiding list where drag ended
        const listEnd = state.find(list => droppableIdEnd === list.id);

        //put the card in the new list
        listEnd.cards.splice(droppableIndexEnd, 0, ...card);
      }

      return newState;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default listReducer;
```

The dummy data is in the initialState.

**since it is not possible to put my code from so many files here, please consider checking out my GitHub repo if necessary.**

https://github.com/abhinav-anshul/consensolabs

Any little help is really appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Kindly approve the answer if found helpful. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Use [store.subscribe()](https://redux.js.org/api/store/#subscribelistener)

You can achieve it with the following steps:

1. Use **store.subscribe()** from the redux API to call a callback function upon completion of each action dispatch.
2. Inside the callback function, fetch the latest redux state by using
   [store.getState()](https://redux.js.org/api/store/#getState) and save it in your local storage.
3. Finally, update your code for creating your store by setting the **initialState** of the store to be the saved state in the local storage (if present), like so:

`var store = createStore(rootReducer, localStorageState || {})`

Comment: I am getting an error, would you mind writing down the code. please check my github repo "https://github.com/abhinav-anshul/consensolabs"

Comment: I am unable to wrap my head around this. Would you mind looking out at my codesandbox please? https://codesandbox.io/s/small-violet-zmbtf

Comment: I'm unable to find any code related to localStorage implementation in your sandbox. Show me what you have tried so far with the localStorage API so that I can tell you where you're wrong.

Comment: I am trying to do the steps suggested by you. In the codesandbox there is a file  called localstorage.js where I am trying to do a callback function. Please check

Comment: Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/github/abhinav-anshul/consensolabs

Comment: I am trying to do something like this : store.subscribe(()=>{
  localStorage.setItem('reduxState', JSON.stringify(store.getState()))
})

Comment: Move your code from `localstrogare.js` to `store/index.js` and remove any mentionings of `redux-persist`

Answer (score 1):

You can use redux-persist to store the state in local storage

In your store.js file do like below to persist the data

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const persistConfig = {
  blacklist: ['form'], //if you don't want to store in local storage
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk);
const store = createStore(persistedReducer, middleware);
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

For more info about redux persist please check the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist)

Comment: I have no idea how this is working, a little explanation would be really helpful

Comment: It will store all the state which you have defined in the root reducer. Redux persist will take those states and store it in local storage. If you want to see the stored data open developer console in chrome and then select -> Application -> LocalStorage.